# Mockito Matcher parameters showing as undefined

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I am trying to Mock a method contained in the Main class of an application. I'd like to test that when all parameters are submitted successfully, the application calls the correct method, uploadFiles. The when - thenReturn pair is shown below:

```
NrClient nrClient = (NrClient)Mockito.mock(NrClient.class);
Mockito.when(nrClient.uploadFiles("DF49ACBC8", anyList(), "dl")).thenReturn("");
```

This shows as a runtime exception: "The method anyString() is undefined for the type MainTest."
I have the imports:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.Matchers;
```

So why would this method be undefined? Is there an issue in my implementation?

I have also tried anyString() and anyInt() with the same result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be getting it as a *compile-time* error, not an exception (unless the actual exception is that you've got an unresolved compile-time error).

Just importing `org.mockito.Matchers` means you can use the name `Matchers` to mean `org.mockito.Matchers` anywhere in the class. If you want to import the *methods*, you need a static wildcard import:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.*;
```

Or specific methods:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyList;
```

Or you could just qualify the method name in the calling code instead:

```
Mockito.when(nrClient.uploadFiles("DF49ACBC8", Matchers.anyList(), "dl"))
       .thenReturn("");
```

Comment: Compile time error is what I had meant to say, thank you for the advice. Your specific method solution works great, thanks Jon

Comment: whoops, i was waiting for the 10 minutes and got carried away with implementing the answer

Answer (score 3):

Use the below import

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*;
```

**Avoid to use Matchers class** because it is now deprecated in order to avoid a name clash with Hamcrest org.hamcrest.Matchers class.